# How can I get data from a zip file and put it in on another zip file?

Tags: java, zip

I have a series of zip files and I want to add their contents to another zip file. How could I do this without extracting? I can't extract a file inside one of the zips because it is called aux.class, which cannot be made on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, Zip files weren't designed to be appended to.

What I would try and do is

- Create a new zip file
- Read the contents of each existing file, writing the contents of the stream to the new zip file
- Rename/delete the old zip (the one you are trying to "append")
- Rename the we zip ino it's place

You could have a look at [Compressing and Decompressing Data Using Java APIs](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/) for some ideas